# Microsoft Azure Mobile Services URL error

Tags: android, azure-mobile-services

I want to create mobile services under Microsoft Azure, but I get this error when I enter my URL:

> Mobile Services is no longer accepting new subscriptions.

[image: error]

Thanks for answering me.

Comment: A code example would really help here.

Comment: It 's note a code but juste an error when the creation of the services you will find the example in this page (second image) https://azure.microsoft.com/fr-fr/documentation/articles/mobile-services-ios-get-started/ the error i've created in my post: mobile services is no longer accepting new subscription

Comment: you will find below a print screen that explains my problem. thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO :) Questions seeking for help must include *the desired behavior*, *a specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example ?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I want to creat a mobile services not with java code but through the website of microsoft azure wich give an interface to create this service, the  error which i get it i put it in my post. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure Mobile Services is deprecated.  Use Azure Mobile Apps instead.

Comment: See [Create an Android app in Azure Mobile Apps](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-android-get-started/).

Comment: Thanks for your comment